# Many-to-Many in Entity Framework

Tags: linq, entity-framework

I have 3 tables where trip and passenger is in many-to-many relationship:

Trip { TripId }

Passenger { PassengerName}

TripPassenger {Tripid, PassengerName}

Assume that i want to retrieve the the list of passenger in a trip, for example all the passenger in trip ID 1:

```
TripId PassengerName
1      admin
1      derp
1      alex
2      admin
```

Any solutions or guidelines?

Comment: @Robaticus, it's absolutely unrelated. Question re-tagged.

Comment: Thanks Darin.  Also, I think OP may have represented his data model incorrectly.  As written, if you want to select a list of passengers in trip 1, you can simply query the TripPassenger table, as it contains both the trip ID and the passenger name.

Answer (score 0):

First Query the Trip table and get the necessary Trip object

```
Trip tripToSearch = context.Trips.SingleOrDefault(trip => trip.Id == 1);
```

then the collection of Passenger objects of the found Trip object

```
tripToSearch.Passengers
```

the above will return a list of Passenger object which are associated with the Trip object which you searched

Comment: That won't work.  There's no direct relationship between Trip and Passenger.

Comment: I think then you can directly query the TripPassenger table as                                         context.TripPassengers.Where(tp => tp.TripId ==1)  this will return all the TripPassenger objects which has TripId ==1

Comment: EF does not map pure join tables by default. There may be an association between trip and passengers, but the OP does not mention it (there is not much info in the post at all).

Comment: Sorry for making you guys confuse, anyhow I have solved my problems. Thank!